# How to improve performance of content view loading on orientation change in Android?

Tags: android, performance, optimization, android-webview, android-orientation

I have a tutorial app which loads a list of tutorial pages[which are web pages]. These pages takes up full screen leaving around 100dp  for menu bars. Though can’t share source code as it is, below is the pseudo code of Tutorial Activity.

```
HashMap<Integer, customWebView > mapPage;
onCreate(){
    updateScreen();
}


updateScreen(){
    Instantiate CustomScrollView(Customized HorizontalScrollView);
    Instantiate scrollViewChildHolder (LinearLayout with horizontal orientation);
    Instantiate mapPage;
        for  index : total page size{
            Instantiate pageHolder(RelativeLayout);
            Instantiate customWebView (Custom WebView);//Takes orientation as one of argument
            Set  html page url;//customWebView has a method loadWebPage() which loads this url.
            Add customWebView  to pageHoler;
            mapPage.put(index, customWebView);
            Add pageHolder to  scrollViewChildHolder;
        }
    //pageNo which will be safely fetched from saved state. So it will be 1 on first start 
    //and on orientation change retains current reading page.
    onPageChange(pageNo);
}

//Custom callback on page swipe by user
@Override
onPageChange(int  pageNo){
    //Custom method which loads html page from url which was set in updateScreen() 
    mapPage.get(pageNo).loadWebPage();
    //unloadNeighbouring pages
    //Will  pick pageNo+2 & pageNo-2 pages and clears their content.
    unloadNeighbouringPagesTo(pageNo);
}
```

**PS:**

1. I do have to add a few buttons over the WebView, hence we use RelativeLayout as page wrapper.
2. I can’t opt to choose adapters[PagerAdapter for ViewPager] as it results in webview flashes its content  all of sudden on load which we can’t afford. So CustomHorizontalSrollView is a must for us.
3. I will be adding around 150+ pages to the scrollview.
4. I have different pages separately for landsape & portrait mode. Hence I need to recreate on orientation change. Also view size varies for each screen orientation.
5. I am not overriding  onConfigurationChanged(..). i.e  On orientation change,  Activity life cycle begins from fresh.

**Problem:**

On orientation change it takes 2-3 seconds to load page content. Also, it seems like app detects orientation change quite late.

Please suggest how I can improve the performance of quick loading on orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing create a single layout file which is contains design for both orientation landscape and portrait . and override OnConfigurationChange();

**mnifest.xml**

```
<activity
            android:name="YourActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" // this will not refresh your activity
             />

@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            //visible landscape layout
            //hide portrait layout
        }else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            //visible portrait layout
            //hide landscape layout
        }
    }
```

Comment: Biraj, Thanks for your input! I tried as you told. Resultant performance is almost same itself. Up on trying your approach, one thing i could conclude is: WebView creation takes longer duration[~= 1700 to 2000 mili seconds].Unfortunately webview cant be initialized in non-ui thread. So,looking for other alternatives...